Expo react native Flatlist with onClick action
I am new to React Native. I am trying to build an app which has categories as items from a flat list
the categories are Service, Review, About, Specialist (The display like this on the app without commas)
My goal is, when the app is opened and I navigate to the Details Screen, contents under the category "Service" should appear and the Category "Service" should have an underline underneath it.
When I click on "Review" the screen should show contents of "Review" category.
Below is the simple code I have but stuck. I AM STILL LEARNING
<View>
      <FlatList
        data={myData}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.nameText}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>{item?.description}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>


In below code at the top you will have your category shown and on selection of category, you will be shown details on screen which corresponds to your category. Kindly go through also feel free to change UI as per your need. Also, I used dummy data, replace them with your api data
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
    import React, {useState} from "react";
    
    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        category: "Service",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        category: "Review",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        category: "About",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        category: "Specialist",
      },
    ];
    
    const data1 = [
      {
        id: 1,
        category: "Service",
        details: "details 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        category: "Service",
        details: "details 2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        category: "Service",
        details: "details 3",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        category: "Service",
        details: "details 4",
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        category: "Review",
        details: "details 5",
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        category: "Review",
        details: "details 6",
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        category: "About",
        details: "details 7",
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        category: "About",
        details: "details 8",
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        category: "Specialist",
        details: "details 9",
      },
    ];
    
    export default function Splash() {
      const [selected, setSelected]=useState(data[0])
      return (
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={[1, 1]}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  {index == 0 && (
                    <View>
                      <FlatList
                        data={data}
                        horizontal
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setSelected(item)} style={{marginLeft:20, backgroundColor:item==selected?'red':'transparent'}}>
                            <Text style={{textDecorationLine:item==selected?'underline':'none', padding:5}}>{item.category}</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                  )}
                  {
                    index==1 && (
                      <View style={{marginTop:40}}>
                        <FlatList
                          data={data1.filter((item)=>item.category==selected.category)}
                          renderItem={({item, index})=>(
                            <View>
                              <Text>{item.details}</Text>
                            </View>
                          )}
                        />
                      </View>
                    )
                  }
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({});


Thank you so much, this did exactly what I wanted.
